# RNFetchBlob can't download properly ( creating 0 B files)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I'm using RNFetchBlob to download some pictures and save them in the download directory. When I press the download button, it says the download finishes but there's just an image file with 0 bytes length in my download directory that obviously can not be opened!

Here is my code:

```
downLoadFile() {
        const Url = 'https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2017/06/05/886719_photo_512x512.png';

        let fileDirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.PictureDir;
        const filePathEnd = constants.download_image_path +
            Url.substring(Url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, Url.lastIndexOf(".")+'.png');

        RNFetchBlob.config({
            fileCache: true,
            path: fileDirs + filePathEnd,
            addAndroidDownloads: {
                notification: true,
                title: "Download Successful",
                description: "An image file.",
                mediaScannable: true
            }
        })
            .fetch("GET", Url, {
                Authorization: "Bearer access-token..."
            })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.contentLength === res.bytesWritten) {
                    console.log("RNFetchBlob.config ok");
                }
            })
            .catch((errorMessage) => {
                console.log(" RNFetchBlob.config error", errorMessage);
            });
    }
```

I get 'RNFetchBlob.config ok' on console and no error seems to occur :|

OS : android

react-native : 55.4

react-native-fetch-blob: 0.10.8

I'm stuck in here for 2 days. Appreciate it if anyone could help me out :)

Comment: Why are you trying to download a png file as jpg?

Comment: @TareqEl-Masri sorry about that.I was just trying different URLs.But It's not the problem. I still face the same issue.

Comment: Have you checked on your Android permissions that you've `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue, but with the newer ReactNativeBlobUtil library.  I can't tell you that this is the "best" fix, but it worked for me.

let DownloadDir = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.dirs.DocumentDir : ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.dirs.DownloadDir;

//res below is the data returned from the fetch. using res.data failed with images (and maybe others?) but reading the file and then writing that data works

let data = await res.readFile('base64');

ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.writeFile(DownloadDir + '/' + name, data, 'base64');
ReactNativeBlobUtil.ios.previewDocument(DownloadDir + '/' + name);